# Django - Model property 'getter'?

Tags: django, django-models

If I had a model like this:

```
  class Entry(models.Model):
 STATUS_LIVE = 1
 STATUS_DRAFT = 2
 STATUS_HIDDEN = 3
 STATUS_CHOICES = (
  (STATUS_LIVE, ('Live')),
  (STATUS_DRAFT, ('Draft')),
  (STATUS_HIDDEN, ('Hidden')),
 )

 id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
 status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
```

And I wanted to show the property 'status' in a view as either 'Live', 'Draft' or 'Hidden' (as opposed to 1, 2 or 3), how would I do this?

It seems Django doesn't have any kind of getter / setter functionality inside of models, I'd like to be able to use entry.status and not something like entry.full_status because it becomes awfully confusing having lots of differently named properties.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would call [`Entry.get_status_display()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).